# Unable to create a Local Database SQLite

Tags: android, database, sqlite, exception, localdb

i'm trying to create a local database on android SQLite, but everytime that i try to create i get this exception on my logcat, why this is happening ?? i already deleted the app and run as a new one...

```
private static final int DATABASE_VERSAO = 1;
public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "STARA_DB";

private static final String TB_CLIENTE = "Table de Clientes";

private final Context context;
private DatabaseHelper DBHelper;
private SQLiteDatabase database;
private static final String TAG = "DBAdapter";

 String TabelaClientes = "CREATE TABLE " 
        + TB_CLIENTE 
        + "(ID_CLIENTE  PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTOINCREMENT, " 
        + "KUNNR TEXT, " 
        + "NAME1 TEXT );";

public ClienteDAO(Context ctx) {
    this.context = ctx;
    DBHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
}

private class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSAO);
    }

    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database) {
        try {
            database.execSQL(TB_CLIENTE);

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase database, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to " + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");

        database.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS" + TB_CLIENTE);
        // onCreate(database);
        onUpgrade(database, oldVersion, newVersion);
    }
public long insertCliente(String KUNNR, String NAME1) {
    ContentValues initialValuesClientes = new ContentValues();
    initialValuesClientes.put("KUNNR", KUNNR);
    initialValuesClientes.put("NAME1", NAME1);

    return database.insert(TB_CLIENTE, null, initialValuesClientes);
}
public List<ClienteModelo> getListaClientes() {

    List<ClienteModelo> clientes = new ArrayList<ClienteModelo>();

    Cursor cCli = DBHelper.getReadableDatabase().rawQuery("Select KUNNR, NAME1 from " + TB_CLIENTE + ";", null);

    while (cCli.moveToNext()) {
        ClienteModelo cliente = new ClienteModelo();

        // cliente.setClienteID(cCli.getLong(cCli.getColumnIndex("ID_CLIENTE")));
        cliente.setKunnr(cCli.getString(cCli.getColumnIndex("KUNNR")));
        cliente.setName1(cCli.getString(cCli.getColumnIndex("NAME1")));

        clientes.add(cliente);
    }

    cCli.close();
    return clientes;

}

public void deleteCliente() {
    database.delete(TB_CLIENTE, null, null);
}
```

And the message on LogCat:

```
no such table: TABLE_CLIENTE
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity    ComponentInfo{stara.formularios/stara.formularios.views.FormNota}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: TABLE_CLIENTE (code 1): , while compiling: Select KUNNR, NAME1 from TABLE_CLIENTE;
Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: TABLE_CLIENTE (code 1): , while compiling: Select KUNNR, NAME1 from TABLE_CLIENTE;"
```

Comment: you might wanna un-install and re-install your app.

Comment: Shouldn't database.execSQL(TB_CLIENTE) be database.execSQL(TabelaClientes) in your onCreate?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have syntax errors in your `CREATE TABLE` you are ignoring.

- `"Table de Clientes"` should probably be a valid identifier like `"TABLE_CLIENTE"` you're using later, according to your stacktrace.
- `ID_CLIENTE  PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTOINCREMENT` needs to have `INTEGER` in it, e.g. `ID_CLIENTE INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT`. The `NOT NULL` is redundant; a primary key cannot be null.
- You need to actually pass the SQL and not the table name to `execSQL()`.
- Remove the `try`-`catch` in your `onCreate()`. The callback needs to throw on error and not ignore problems.

After the changes, uninstall your app so the old database file gets removed.

Answer (score 1):

In Oncreate You passed Wrong argument to create table:

```
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database) {
        try {
            database.execSQL(TabelaClientes);

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

And table name should not contain any spaces.

```
private static final String TB_CLIENTE = "Table_de_Clientes";
```